# Depth First Analysis Python

Tags: python, depth-first-search

This program takes, adjacency matrix as input.

```
def DFS(matrix):
stack = [1]

dimen=len(matrix)

rslt = [1]

while stack:
    current=matrix[stack[-1]-1]
    for j in range(len(current)):

            if current[j]==1 :
                a=False
                if (j+1 not in stack) and (j+1 not in rslt):
                    stack.append(j+1)
                    rslt.append(j+1)
                    a= True
                    break
            if j+1== len(current):
                current.append("farigh")

    if len(matrix[stack[-1]-1]) == dimen and a == True :
        b=0
        current2= matrix[stack[-1]-1]

        for e in range(len(current2)):
            if current2[e]==1:
                b=b+1
        if b==1:
            stack.pop()
            current2.append("Hogya")
            #print("appended")

    if current[-1]=="farigh":
        stack.pop()


    print(stack,"stack")
    print(rslt,"rslt")
```

Is it working the way it should. I am not returning anything from this function as it is still in testing phase.

Comment: I think this kind of question should be asked in [Coder Review Stack Site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: can x contain anything but open and close parens? Also '())(' would seem to pass your tests but is probably not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is basically checking that there are the same number of open and closing parenthesis. You could have written something like:

```
if x[0]!=")" and x[len(x)-1]!="(":
    n_op = sum(c == '(' for c in input_string)
    n_cl = sum(c == ')' for c in input_string)

    if n_op==n_cl:
        print("True")

#        # This code is redundant, it only clears the lists
#        for i in range(len(op)):
#            op.pop()
#            cl.pop()

        print("okkay hai boss")
    else:
        print("False")
```

However, your code would fail with a string like `())(()`, where you will be closing one more parenthesis that you are opening. You are addressing this case in your first condition by ensuring that the first character is not a closing parenthesis, but it is not enough.

Another point is that you are assuming that everything that is not `(` is `)`. I do not know your needs exactly, but it would be safer to check (just in case).

Instead, you could use the following code:

```
pending = 0
for c in x:
    # opening parentheses increase the count
    if c == '(':
        pending += 1
    # closing parentheses decrease the count
    elif c == ')':
        pending -= 1
    # if the count becomes negative, abort
    if pending < 0:
        break

# at the end of the loop a positive number means too many opening parentheses
# a negative value means that at some point there were too many closing parentheses
# and a zero means all is ok
if pending == 0:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```